# Downgrade openmpi v2.1.1 to v2.0.2

Tags: 18.04, downgrade, mpi

I have installed openmpi on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS using

```
$sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev

$ mpirun -version
mpirun (Open MPI) 2.1.1
```

How can I downgrade it to v2.0.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Removing new packages packages first

```
sudo apt remove libopenmpi2 openmpi-common libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin
```

#### Add debian repository

(I found this versions here)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free'
```

#### check available versions (optional)

```
apt list -a openmpi-bin
```

#### install old versions

```
sudo apt install openmpi-bin=2.0.2-2 openmpi-common=2.0.2-2 libopenmpi-dev=2.0.2-2 libopenmpi2=2.0.2-2
```

#### Test

```
mpirun -version
```

Comment: Thanks also @Jim for good edit.

Comment: Your welcome, it's our duty as community member to tidy things up.